# How does setInterval() work with button.onclick

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want the alertMe function to be called only when the button is clicked, but it gets called (the setInterval gets called which calls that) AS SOON AS THE PAGE LOADS. But if I take the pageLoad function away, then startButton is null and I can't do anything with it.Thanks in advance, guys!

```
/when user clicks start, start the animation
window.onload = pageLoad;

function pageLoad() {
    var startButton = document.getElementById("start");

    startButton.onclick = setInterval(alertMe,200);
}

function alertMe() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function pageLoad() {
    var startButton = document.getElementById("start");

    startButton.onclick = alertMe;
}

function alertMe() {
  setInterval(function(){
    alert("hi");
  },200);
}
```

Move your interval inside the `alertMe` function, and pass that as a reference to `startButton.onclick`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gHS4a/

Comment: Because you want it to start looping *after* the button is clicked.

Comment: isn't that what the "onlick" function signifies...that the button has been clicked?

Comment: Right, but it's assigned to the return value of your statement, rather than a function it can execute.

Comment: @AlexSilverman Keep in mind that multiple button clicks will cause separate timers to accumulate.

Answer (score 3):

basically you need to do it like this:

```
startButton.onclick = function() {
    interval = setInterval(alertMe, 200);
}
```

what it does is it sends reference to the `alertMe` function

another way would be:

```
startButton.onclick = function() {
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        alertMe();
    }, 200);
}
```

which would send a reference to an anonymous function which will call the `alertMe` function